# Redirect output to file, then write sentence with exit code to end of same file

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, redirection

I am looking to redirect all the output from a python script to `output.out`, then upon completion of the python script, write `Exited with code: <EXIT CODE HERE>` to the same file where `<EXIT CODE HERE>` is the exit code of the python process/script.

I need to do this all in one line which I will be passing to a `bash -c` call. I can get the redirection by doing something like this:

`bash -c 'python /tmp/test.py > /tmp/all.out 2>&1'`

But how do I then take the exit code and write it to `/tmp/all.out`?

Answer (score 1):

```
bash -c 'python /tmp/test.py; echo Exited with code: $?' &> /tmp/all.out
```

or

```
bash -c '(python /tmp/test.py; echo Exited with code: $?) &> /tmp/all.out'
```

or

```
bash -c 'python /tmp/test.py &> /tmp/all.out; echo Exited with code: $? &>> /tmp/all.out'
```